# XAMPP Update Curl Library

Tags: xampp, xampp-vm

I have xampp-osx-7.4.9 which is the latest version at this moment. I need curl library higher than curl 7.6 but it comes with curl 7.53.1.

How can I update curl on XAMPP VM or XAMPP Installer

Comment: Looking for the same thing